# How do I add value to my Method call from my Sub class to Main?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, extends, method-call

The string value seems to appear yet I can not add a value to my calculations in the fulltime and part time.

This is the Main class for my inheritance

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RunEmployee1 {
    private static String name;
    private static double rate;
    private static int hour;
    private static double wage1;
    private static double salary;
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public double getMonthlySalary(){
        return salary;
    }
    public double getWage1(){
        return wage1;
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        char position;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Employee name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type F for Full time or P for Part time: ");
        System.out.println("Use Capital Letter only!");
        position = sc.next().charAt(0);
        switch(position){
            case 'F':
                System.out.println("You are a Full time Employee!");
                System.out.println("Enter your Monthly Wage: ");
                salary = sc.nextDouble();
                break;
            case 'P':
                System.out.println("You are a Part time Employee!");
                System.out.println("Enter the number of hours you worked in: ");
                hour = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the hourly rate you are working in: ");
                rate = sc.nextDouble();
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("You are not an Employee!");
        }
        Employee1 em1 = new Employee1();
        FullTimeEmployee1 em2 = new FullTimeEmployee1();
        PartTimeEmployee1 em3 = new PartTimeEmployee1();
        em1.getName();
        em1.writeOutput1();
        em2.getMonthlySalary();
        em2.writeOutput2(salary);
        em3.getWage1();
        em3.writeOutput3(wage1);
    }
}
```

this is the child class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FullTimeEmployee1 extends RunEmployee1{
    private static double salary;
    private static double newMonthlySalary;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void setMonthlySalary(double newMonthlySalary){
        this.salary = newMonthlySalary;
        newMonthlySalary = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    public double getMonthlySalary(double newMonthlySalary){
        salary = newMonthlySalary;
        return salary = newMonthlySalary;
    }
    public void writeOutput2(double getMonthlySalary){
        System.out.println("Employee's Full time Monthly Salary is: " +getMonthlySalary());
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FullTimeEmployee1 em2 = new FullTimeEmployee1();
        System.out.println("You are a Full time Employee!");
        System.out.println("Enter your Monthly Wage: ");
        salary = sc.nextDouble();
        em2.getMonthlySalary();
        em2.writeOutput2(salary);
    }
}
 and 

import java.util.Scanner;
public class PartTimeEmployee1 extends RunEmployee1 {
    private static double rate;
    private static int hour;
    private static double wage1;
    private static double newMonthlyWage1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void setWage1(int hourWorked, double RatePerHour, double newMonthlyWage) {
        RatePerHour = rate;
        hourWorked = hour;
        double wage1 = RatePerHour * hourWorked;
        this.wage1 = newMonthlyWage;
        newMonthlyWage = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    public double getWage1(double newMonthlyWage) {
        wage1 = newMonthlyWage;
        return wage1 = newMonthlyWage;
    }
    public void writeOutput3(double getWage1) {
        System.out.println("Employee's Part time Monthly Wage is: " + +getWage1());
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PartTimeEmployee1 em3 = new PartTimeEmployee1();
        System.out.println("You are a Part time Employee!");
        System.out.println("Enter the number of hours you worked in: ");
        hour = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the hourly rate you are working in: ");
        rate = sc.nextDouble();
        wage1 = rate * hour;
        em3.getWage1();
        em3.writeOutput3(wage1);
    }
}
```

I should be showing results to the Salary value for both Fulltime and Parttime sub class.

> Enter Employee name:  Name Type F for Full time or P for Part time:
> Use Capital Letter only! P You are a Part time Employee! Enter the
> number of hours you worked in:  5 Enter the hourly rate you are
> working in:  100 Employee's name is: Name Employee's Full time Monthly
> Salary is: 0.0 Employee's Part time Monthly Wage is: 0.0

[expected result with value for both the salary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpGbF.png)

Comment: Please edit and add the result in image as a text in your question as well.

Comment: why do you have three main methods?

Comment: @Stultuske one for each sub class in different java file so I can inherit their methods or is that wrong?

Comment: You're calling `em2.getMonthlySalary()` but you're not doing anything with the result.

Comment: How do you expect to use the local fields of a method in another method in another class?